no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'boost::uuids::uuid::data_type' to 'utils::span<std::uint8_t>'
I am trying to run userver (https://userver.tech/) on MacOS
I am following this tutorial: https://userver.tech/d3/da9/md_en_2userver_2tutorial_2build.html
My actions:
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/userver-framework/service_template.git && \
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/userver-framework/userver.git service_template/third_party/userver && \
cd service_template

brew install $(cat third_party/userver/scripts/docs/en/deps/macos.md | tr '\n' ' ')


make build-release && \
make service-start-release

I have an error:
 25%] Building CXX object third_party/userver/universal/CMakeFiles/userver-universal.dir/src/utils/impl/byte_utils.cpp.o
/Users/mascai/root_folder/dev/projects/49_USERVER/01_tutorial/service_template/third_party/userver/universal/src/utils/boost_uuid7.cpp:49:27: error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'boost::uuids::uuid::data_type' to 'utils::span<std::uint8_t>' (aka 'span<unsigned char>')
      GenerateRandomBlock(utils::span<std::uint8_t>(uuid.data).subspan(8));
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


I guess the problem deals with Boost version. My Boost version is 1.86.0 and clang 13.0.0.

In Boost 1.86.0, the uuid::data member is of type uuid::data_type, which is a struct type that holds a uint8_t[] array. You can't make a span out of a struct, hence the compiler error.
In Boost 1.85.0, the uuid::data member was the actual uint8_t[] array, which a span can be created from.
So, clearly, userver hasn't been updated to account for that change in Boost yet.  So, you will have to either:

contact the userver author for an update that supports Boost 1.86.0 properly.

change userver yourself to construct the span using either:

uuid's begin() and end() iterators, eg:
utils::span<std::uint8_t>(uuid.begin(), uuid.end())


uuid's data() pointer and size(), eg:
utils::span<std::uint8_t>(uuid.data(), uuid.size())


uuid::data's conversion operator to a uint8_t[] array, eg:
using uuid_arr_type = std::uint8_t[16];
utils::span<std::uint8_t>(static_cast<uuid_arr_type&>(uuid.data))




downgrade your Boost version to 1.85.0.


